# getting correct json response

Tags: php, json

I am getting data from database and showing it in form of json

Here is how I do:

```
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {   
        array_push($result1,$row);
    }
    echo  $result1 = json_encode($result1,true);
```

which gives result in this form

```
[["29"],["13702210"],["892344"],["Multi AxleB9RVolvo"],["10:30AM"],["06:45PM"],["14"],["37"],["650"]]
```

This prints only the database value fetching from table. But this response marked as invalid json response

Each of the fields has name in table. 
I want to see json response in this form:;

```
{"routes":[{"route":{"routeid":29,"Service_Name":13702210,"Service_Number":892344,"BusType":"Multi AxleB9RVolvo","DepartureTime":"10:30AM","ArravalTime":"06:45PM","available_seats":14,"Total_SeatCapacity":37,"Fare":"650"}},{"route":{"routeid":29,"Service_Name":13702210,"Service_Number":892344,"BusType":"Multi AxleB9RVolvo","DepartureTime":"10:30AM","ArravalTime":"06:45PM","available_seats":14,"Total_SeatCapacity":37,"Fare":"650"}},{"route":{"routeid":29,"Service_Name":13702210,"Service_Number":892344,"BusType":"Multi AxleB9RVolvo","DepartureTime":"10:30AM","ArravalTime":"06:45PM","available_seats":14,"Total_SeatCapacity":37,"Fare":"650"}}]}
```

This contains name and nested preview. How can I do this?

Comment: you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in order to return key value array. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the strucutre of your database, but:

```
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    array_push($result1,$row);
}
echo  $result1 = json_encode(array('routes' => $result1));
```

May give you the result you want. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns the table rows as associative arrays which will provide keys.

Then `array('routes' => $result1)` creates a new associative array with the key 'routes' matching your index of arrays.

If they keys aren't correct in your sql response you could try using `select field_name as alias_name` in your SQL query to return the appropriate field names.

The real trick here is setting up associative arrays with appropriate keys for each value so that `json_encode` creates objects rather than lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use associative array, use this;

```
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    array_push($result1,$row);
}
echo  $result1 = json_encode($result1,true); 
// for `routes` parent
// echo  $result1 = json_encode(array("routes" => $result1));
```

Comment: Most likely you've confused `json_encode` with `json_decode`. `json_encode` expect 2nd parameter to be `int` (bitmasked options).

Comment: @hindmost thanks for your warning, I have not seen that. Refactored